# how do i control height of a row

Tags: html, css

i am making something similar to https://products.office.com/en-US/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=2

i am using this theme http://preview.themeforest.net/item/trizzy-multipurpose-ecommerce-html-template/full_screen_preview/7950329 and the pricing tables that i am using are under shortcodes --> pricing tables

http://77.104.156.45/~mdsc1109/office365.php is what i did until now. scroll down and click on the buy now of business plan

the code is:-

```html
<div class="plan color-1 four columns">
  <div class="plan-price" style="visibility: hidden">
    <h3>Standard<br>Standard</h3>
    <span class="plan-currency">$</span>
    <span class="value">19,90</span>
    <span class="period">/ per month</span>
  </div>
  <div class="plan-features">
    <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="plan color-1 four columns">
  <div class="plan-price">
    <h3>Office 365<br>Business</h3>
    <span class="plan-currency">$</span>
    <span class="value">19,90</span>
    <span class="period">/ per month</span>
  </div>
  <div class="plan-features">
    <ul>
      <li>Best for businesses that need Office applications plus cloud file storage and sharing. Business email not included.</li>
      <li>10 Email Accounts</li>
      <li>5GB Monthly Bandwidth</li>
      <li>Unlimited Subdomains</li>
      <li>Automatic Cloud Backup</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="plan color-1 four columns">
  <div class="plan-price">
    <h3>Office 365<br>Business Premium</h3>
    <span class="plan-currency">$</span>
    <span class="value">19,90</span>
    <span class="period">/ per month</span>
  </div>
  <div class="plan-features">
    <ul>
      <li>Best for businesses that need business email, Office applications, and other business services.</li>
      <li>10 Email Accounts</li>
      <li>5GB Monthly Bandwidth</li>
      <li>Unlimited Subdomains</li>
      <li>Automatic Cloud Backup</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="plan color-1 four columns">
  <div class="plan-price">
    <h3>Office 365<br>Business Essentials</h3>
    <span class="plan-currency">$</span>
    <span class="value">19,90</span>
    <span class="period">/ per month</span>
  </div>
  <div class="plan-features">
    <ul>
      <li>Best for businesses that need business email and other business services. Office applications not included.</li>
      <li>10 Email Accounts</li>
      <li>5GB Monthly Bandwidth</li>
      <li>Unlimited Subdomains</li>
      <li>Automatic Cloud Backup</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

how do i control the spacing so i can make rows? for example i want to put gap above and below each "Best for businesses that need..." in the 3 columns and under it i want to put "Office applications included" in each column and i want them to be all in the same row like in the microsoft website

one way of doing that is by adding empty li, padding top or padding bottom in each column and i have to repeat it for every row. this is a bad way to do it because if i change the text in any place then the gap will get messed up and i have to adjust the gap in each column

is there a better way of doing it? can i add styles to the 1,2,3,4... on the very left and i control the gaps for the whole row by using those styles? for example i set a height for 1 and that height applies to the whole row. if yes then how i do that? I am not sure if that is possible in the current code structure. This is because each column is in a div so any styles that I add to a column will only affect the div that the column is in and it won't affect a column in another way so the only option is to do the bad way that I don't want to do

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into **Flexbox Layout**, because it solves your exact situation. This is the best article/tutorial, in my opinion, about **Flexbox**:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

> The Flexbox Layout (Flexible Box) module (currently a W3C Last Call
>   Working Draft) aims at providing a more efficient way to lay out,
>   align and distribute space among items in a container, even when their
>   size is unknown and/or dynamic (thus the word "flex").

Actually if you look into the link you posted as an example (the Office product page), they're using Flexbox too. Open the inspector and have a look at the styles, that is exactly what you want to replicate.

In your code, you have a "container" and then four divs that are displayed as columns:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 20px">

            <div class="four columns">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h3>Business Plan</h3>
                    <p>text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text.</p>
                    <br>
                    <a id="bp">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h3>Exchange Plan</h3>
                    <p>text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text.</p>
                    <br>
                    <a id="exp">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="four columns">
                <div class="content-box">
                    <h3>Enterprise Plan</h3>
                    <p>text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text.</p>
                    <br>
                    <a id="enp">Buy Now</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="four columns">
            <div class="content-box">
                <h3>Education Plan</h3>
                <p>text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text. text.</p>
                <br>
                <a id="edp">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

So try this CSS:

```
.container {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;

  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Also check this interactive demo where you can see how you can change the direction of your flex items within the container:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction

In your case, you want you items to be columns, but if you wanted them to be rows, you can achieve that by doing:

```
flex-direction: row;
```

Finally, to "control the gaps", you can use this:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/

With justify-content, you can control how items align. It accepts these values:

- flex-start (default): items are packed toward the start line
- flex-end: items are packed toward to end line
- center: items are centered along the line
- space-between: items are evenly distributed in the line; first item is on the start line, last item on the end
- line space-around: items are evenly distributed in the line with
  equal space around them
- space-evenly: items are distributed so that
  the spacing between any two adjacent alignment subjects, before the
  first alignment subject, and after the last alignment subject is the
  same

And here you can see it in action:

[justify-content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl5wZ.jpg)

I hope it helps!

Comment: i will try it. can you please tell me exactly what to do? the code that you pasted is for the content boxes. these are ok. i want to fix the code of the pricing table that shows when u click on buy now